# Stable results with TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

What would be a good way to ensure TensorFlow results persist across
different runs? I can't find much information on e.g. seeding random weight initialization, so my results tend to differ with every run.

Answer (score 7):

The API method [`tf.set_random_seed()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/constant_op.html#set_random_seed) can be used to set a random seed that will be used in all TensorFlow random operations (including the usual random weight initializers and [tf.RandomShuffleQueue](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#RandomShuffleQueue)).